# SQL: Joining two tables to select multiple columns referenced in another table

Tags: sql, join, stored-procedures

I got stuck at one point. I have a table structure as

[image]

I Need result as

[image]

I tried to join, Union etc of tables,but I am not able to get it.
Can you please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

*Assuming your first table is `Ring` and the second one is `RingTone`*

You have to `JOIN` to the `Ring` table twice:

```
SELECT
    rt.ID,
    DayRingTone = r1.RingName,
    NightRingTone = r2.RingName
FROM RingTone rt
INNER JOIN Ring r1
    ON rt.DayRingTone = r1.RingID
INNER JOIN Ring r2
    ON rt.NightRingTone = r2.RingID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
SELECT
    rt.ID,
    DayRingTone = b.RingName,
    NightRingTone = c.RingName
FROM tableringtone a
INNER JOIN tablering b
    ON a.DayRingTone = b.RingID
INNER JOIN tablering c
    ON a.NightRingTone = c.RingID
```